# How to upload files to different folders based on responses in google form

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms

[this is my form ]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu8uf.png)

I am trying to move the video uploaded to the folder of same name of the country after the response is submitted, i have setup the folder of same name on my drive. this form is linked to spreadsheet which I am using to move the uploaded files to the folders.

```
// names and IDs of your destination folders

var folders = {
  'USA' : '1W8MNqQ7jY9m-jTfS2zHYQVPl-KxI1Ty_', // <-- you have to change ### with a real ID
  'CANADA' : '1edeaWuqhumD_KppuqlUnZZib2TrDVQH0',
  'UK' : '1B_V_pYgKDwJd42kCWOemIjJN6tZLtmyN',
  'AUSTRALIA' : '1ixPoA5fHFmjBSILpY5XDt8cvqmGFwbjL',
  'EUROPE' : '18smSdxegXbPFMnWXZtweaeA9htDv2PXC',
  'ASIA' : '1J9fJKAtBNnhlLIIyhZeiNnvZEHh79LIZ',
  'AFRICA' : '1ICPozBV_xDZ4ILFJ1J1vRSDjVYBRU_Nx',
  'SOUTH/LATIN AMERICA' : '1_F4MQxmpjvxTdJCNzcBHuUW1z1ZLbS_V'
}

function move_file_to_folder(e) {

  // get folder ID from folders object
  var folder_id = folders[e.namedValues['COUNTRY'][0]]; // <-- the name from the named value 'Folder'

  // get file ID from the form
  var file_id = e.namedValues['VIDEO UPLOAD'][0].split('id=')[1]; // <-- the url from the named value 'File'

  // move the file into the folder
  DriveApp.getFileById(file_id).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id));
}


// this function should be run just once to install the trigger

function install_OnFormSubmitTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('move_file_to_folder')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}
```

what am i doing wrong, as it is giving me error.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `what am i doing wrong, as it is giving me error.`, I cannot understand the current issue of your showing script. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You can also do this with the Document Studio add-on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WLzJDqNRU4 - (I am the author)

Comment: Sorry this is the error I am getting. 

Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'namedValues')
move_file_to_folder @ Code.gs:17

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Sorry this is the error I am getting. Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'namedValues') move_file_to_folder @ Code.gs:17`, how did you run your showing script?

Comment: I just ran through the app script module in spreadsheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I just ran through the app script module in spreadsheets.`, I cannot understand how you ran your showing script. But, I think that in your showing script, it is required to run the function `move_file_to_folder` with the OnSubmit trigger. How about this? If my understanding is correct, first, you are required to run `install_OnFormSubmitTrigger` with the script editor.

Comment: And then, you are required to submit your Google Form. By this, the function `move_file_to_folder` is automatically run with the OnSubmit trigger. Is this your expected result?

Comment: yes that would be ideal and it is supposed to be the case, However I have made multiple entries of the form and it has not worked.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From `yes that would be ideal and it is supposed to be the case,`, I understood that you wanted to run `move_file_to_folder` with the OnSubmit trigger. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand `I just ran through the app script module in spreadsheets.` from your reply, can I ask you about the details of it? Also, can I ask you about the details of the relationship between `However I have made multiple entries of the form and it has not worked.` and your question and your current issue?

Comment: So the google form as indicated on the picture is where a user would upload the files. the form is linked to spreadsheet where I am running this script. i have deployed this script so on each of the form submit this will run automatically and then the files will be transferred to appropriate folder as outlined on the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that in your showing script, when the function `move_file_to_folder` is automatically run with the OnSubmit trigger by giving valid values of the event object, the script works and the uploaded file is moved to the specific folder retrieved from `folders`. But, you say `it has not worked`. In this case, it is required to correctly replicate your situation. So, I would like to try to correctly replicate your situation. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: I would like to confirm about `I just ran through the app script module in spreadsheets.`. In your situation, your function `move_file_to_folder` is automatically run with the OnSubmit trigger, and under this condition, you say `I am getting. Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'namedValues') move_file_to_folder @ Code.gs:17` and `it has not worked.`. Is my understanding correct? Because I cannot still understand how you ran your script. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Some trouble-shooting is required. Kamal Parajuli, would you please `1)` insert this line `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` as the first line of code in function `move_file_to_folder`; `2)` save the amended function; `3)` submit a form with answers to both quetsions; `4)` take a snapshot of the `Executions tab` for your submission and `5) ` include the snapshot in the body of the question. This will enable you and users to identify the Event Objects returned by the function as well as the specific text of any  error.